# COPYing a file in a Dockerfile, no such file or directory?

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile set up in my root (~) folder. The first three lines of my file look like this:

```
COPY file1 /root/folder/
COPY file2 /root/folder/
COPY file3 /root/folder/
```

but it returns the following error for each line:

> No such file or directory

The files are in the same directory as my Dockerfile and I am running the command `docker build - < Dockerfile` in the same directory in terminal as well.

What am I doing wrong here exactly?

Comment: I had this problem, then noticed the .dockerignore file was ignoring the file I was trying to copy.  Solution by jinschubert: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1922

Comment: @JStrahl, thanks to the 3 year younger version of you who decided to post when you did. It perhaps saved my entire evening. I am now aware of the existence of ".dockerignore" files.

Comment: I think my issue may be related to .sh files being executable, but I really have no idea. I'm resorting to dynamically creating my (fortunately tiny) shell script via `RUN echo "npm run start;" >> /docker-entrypoint.d/40-npm-start.sh` https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32816#issuecomment-910030001

Comment: Unbelievable - can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks @JStrahl!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The COPY instruction in the `Dockerfile` copies the files in `src` to the `dest` folder. Looks like you are either missing the `file1`, `file2` and `file3` or trying to build the `Dockerfile` from the wrong folder.

[Refer Dockerfile Doc](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy)

Also the command for building the `Dockerfile` should be something like.

```
cd into/the/folder/
docker build -t sometagname .
```

Comment: I found out after properly reading your link that the DockerFile should not be in the root folder at all. Moved everything to the subdirectory, ran the build command and it runs. Your answer was most helpful so I shall mark it as correct.

Comment: Also check if there is (not) a Docker Ignore file.

Comment: why can't I use `docker build -t sometagname ./somefolder` instead?

Answer (score 444):

Do check the `.dockerignore` file too.

I know this is a very rare case, but I had that file mentioned there.

Comment: oh my god thank you. I was changing the name of a Java project (and thus artifact and build dir) , and `ripgrep` doesn't search in dotfiles so I didn't see the last pesky reference to the old directory.

Comment: thanks for the headsup, in my case i was using visual studio wizard for docker and it added a .dockerignore with * in the first line :(

Comment: For some reason, my default .dockerignore has **\bin in it.  I'm sure it was generated by Docker desktop.

Comment: ahhghgghghg seems like not such a rare case after all!!!.
Wouldn´t have figured it out in a million years.
Added the directory a while back and totally forgot. The reason for adding it being it makes any build extremely slow, think it has do with git...

Comment: @swateek any idea where the .dockerignore file is located?

Comment: @Diana please check the location which is your project home (typically where `.git` would also be present) or where your `docker-compose.yml` file is present.

Comment: Saves me hours after spending extra hours. My orgs docker ignore ignores everything by default :/

Comment: i am working off another persons project, I just spent 3 hours wondering why the file that's RIGHT THERE can't be found... it was .dockerignore... ty

Answer (score 74):

It is possibly caused by you are referring `file1`/`file2`/`file3` as an absolute path which is not in build context, Docker only searches the path in the build context.

E.g. if you use `COPY /home/yourname/file1`, Docker build interprets it as `${docker build working directory}/home/yourname/file1`, if no file with the same name here, no file or directory error is thrown.

Refer to [One of the docker issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4592)

Comment: there is some sort of absolute path problem, I can only "COPY relative/path/x ." I cannot "COPY /absolute/path/y .", anybody know why?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Dockerfiles are supposed to be runnable independently on host machine and shipped with additional files available in paths relative to Dockerfile. Using absolute paths would make it runnable only on your machine.

Comment: That was my problem with `ADD` directive as well, thank you.

Comment: I did not know this. Changing it so that the file was included alongside the dockerfile actually worked perfectly for me. When I had it from some other source location (as a full path e.g. /dir/dir2/file) it wasn't working. It works if it's in the some directory as the dockerfile or it's children

Answer (score 61):

Seems that the commands:

```
docker build -t imagename .
```

and:

```
docker build -t imagename - < Dockerfile2
```

are not executed the same way. If you want to build 2 docker images from within one folder with Dockerfile and Dockerfile2, the COPY command cannot be used in the second example using stdin (< Dockerfile2).
Instead you have to use:

```
docker build -t imagename -f Dockerfile2 .
```

Then COPY does work as expected.

Comment: thanks for this. Kind of annoying the official docs list the pipe method front and center, don't show the more 'normal' -f flag based method, and don't discuss the important impact on COPY as a result.

Answer (score 30):

Running `docker build . -f docker/development/Dockerfile` worked,  which allows you to run your docker file from a specified directory other than the root of your application.

Use `-f` or `--file` to specify the name and location of the `Dockerfile`.

This happened to me when trying to run the docker file from a different directory.

I had the `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder929708051/XXXX: no such file or directory` and managed to resolve this by specifying the docker file.

It was `docker build docker/development/Dockerfile` that caused this issue for me.

I found it strange at first because when i had the `Dockerfile` in the apps root directory it worked fine. This will help if you want to manage your environment docker files a little better.

Comment: Because of the Docker context and constraints on relative path, this was very useful as I had not thought about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I just experienced this problem and none of the suggestions here solved my problem.
Turns out **I had the wrong line endings** in my file, and had to change them to the appropriate line endings. (In this case from CRLF to LF, so Ubuntu 14.04 would recognize the script, which I had been editing on windows.)

I changed the line endings using VSCode, and most code editors should have the option of choosing line endings.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for this - a rather insidious problem. I had a similar issue with a repository pulled onto a Windows machine. The file I was trying to copy into the container was a shell script and wouldn't execute until I changed the line endings manually.

Comment: Wow, never would've guessed it but this fixed my issue. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 12):

Doing a `docker build - < Dockerfile` or `Get-Content .\Dockerfile | Docker build -`on PS might not be getting the context. I would recommend you use

```
Docker build -f .\Path\Dockerfile .
```

Answer (score 7):

I feel a little stupid, but my issue was that I was running docker-compose, and my Dockerfile was in a ./deploy subdirectory. My ADD reference needed to be relative to the root of the project, not the Dockerfile.

Changed:
ADD ./file.tar.gz /etc/folder/
to:
ADD ./deploy/file.tar.gz /etc/folder/

Anyhow, thought I'd post in case someone ran into the same issue.

Comment: Any idea about how to change the copy context?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is here:

> **If you build using STDIN (docker build - < somefile), there is no
> build context, so COPY can’t be used.**

For more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Just build docker in this way:

```
docker build -t name-of-your-tag .
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution and the best practice:

You need to create a resources folder where you can keep all your files you want to copy.

```
├── Dockerfile
└── resources
│     ├── file1.txt
│     ├── file2.js
```

The command for copying files should be specified this way:

```
COPY resources /root/folder/
```

where

***resources** - your local folder which you created in the same folder where Dockerfile is

***/root/folder/** - folder at your container

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but something to point out. If you think everything is as its supposed to, check your .gitignore file :)

You might have the folder locally, but if the folder is in your git ignore then its not on the server, which means Docker cannot find that folder as it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Previous calls on COPY may be changing the directory.

```
COPY ./server/package.json ./server      # this passes, but the dest ./server is considered a file

COPY ./server/dist ./server/dist         # error, ./server/dist is not a directory
```

Add a trailing slash to the first call

```
COPY ./server/package.json ./server/
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar and thanks to [tslegaitis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2768651/tslegaitis)'s answer, after

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

it shows

```
Check the gcloud log [/home/USER/.config/gcloud/logs/2020.05.24/21.12.04.NUMBERS.log] to see which files and the contents of the
default gcloudignore file used (see `$ gcloud topic gcloudignore` to learn
more).
```

Checking that log, it says that docker will use `.gitignore`:

```
DATE Using default gcloudignore file:
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
# ...

.gitignore
```

So I fixed my `.gitignore` (I use it as whitelist instead) and docker copied the file.

[I added the answer because I have not enough reputation to comment]

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem even though my source directory was in the correct build context. Found the reason was that my source directory was a symbolic link to a location outside the build context.

For example my Dockerfile contains the following:

```
COPY dir1 /tmp
```

If `dir1` is a symbolic link the `COPY` command is not working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

For following error,

```
COPY failed: stat /<**path**> :no such file or directory
```

I got it around by restarting docker service.

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Answer (score 1):

File not found error with Docker put_archive.  I am using the Python API for docker. 
Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b

```
docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/39d58e00519ba4171815ee4444f3c43d2c6a7e285102747398f6788e39ee0e87/var/lib/neo4j/certificates: no such file or directory")
```

I am unable to copy files to a created docker container.

```
con = cli.create_container(...)
cli.put_archive(...)
cli.start(con['Id'])
```

If I change the order of operation there is no error and the files are copied exactly to were I want them. So I know my code is working and doing what I want it to do.  But its important to copy configuration files to a container before it is started. Coping the files after the start cuases the container to start with a default configuration and not the custom configuration which needs to be copied into place before the container is started. Docker claims that this issue is closed but it is still affecting my application.

This works; Same code different execution order.

```
con = cli.create_container(...)
cli.start(con['Id'])
cli.put_archive(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that you did the right thing, but docker still complains, take a look at this issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27134.
I got burnt by this, and it seems like restarting docker engine `service docker restart` will just fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a fix on this and the folder i was ADD or COPY'ing was not in the build folder, multiple directories above or referenced from /

Moving the folder from outside the build folder into the build folder fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

one of the way to don't use stdin and keep the context is:

1) in your Dockerfile, you should add

```
ADD /your_dir_to_copy /location_in_container
```

2) after, you should go on the parent of /your_dir_to_copy dir

2) then run this command

```
sudo docker build . -t (image/name) -f path_of_your_dockerfile/Dockerfile
```

3) after you create your container

```
docker run -ti --rm cordova bash
```

4) After you will get your directory copied in your container

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this. Copying some directories didn't work. Copying files did. It turned out to be because files contained in .gitignore (not just .dockerignore) are also ignored. See: https://github.com/zeit/now/issues/790

Comment: dozens of references for COPY failing to copy -- this is one of few to reference `.dockerignore` as a culprit

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this myself, and none of the solutions here worked.

Finally, the reason was that I **was running wrong container**. I was building *container/name* and was running *container/name:1.0*, which was built previously.

In other words, check that you build & run exactly the same container.

Answer (score 0):

So this has happened a couple of times just recently. As a .Net dev, using VisualStudio I changed my build name from `SomeThing` to `Something` as the DLL name but this does not change the .csproj file which stays `SomeThing.csproj`

The Dockerfile uses linux case-sensitive filenames, so the newly autogenerated Dockerfile was trying to copy `Something.csproj` which it couldn't find. So manually renaming that file (making it lowercase) got it all working

But...here's a cautionary warning. This filename change on my Windows laptop does not get picked up by Git so the repo source was still `SomeThing.csproj` on the repo and during the CI/CD process, the Docker build failed for the same reasons...

I had to change the filename directly as a commit on the repo....nasty little workaround but got me going

tl;dr If on Windows O/S check for filename case sensitivity and be aware local file renames do not get picked up as Git change so make sure your repo is also modified if using CI/CD

Answer (score 0):

In my case docker compose file itself specified another build context:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    ...
    build: ../.docker/mysql
```

So check the compose file itself for another build context.

Answer (score 0):

Re-Downoloading the base image fixes my following error. Hope this could help you.

```
docker build \
    -f Dockerfile \
    -t yifengchennnn/smart-search:huggingface-dependencies \
    .
[+] Building 0.0s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                              docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 83B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:7                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 43B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/centos:7                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] COPY huggingface.tar.gz /root/                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
------
 > [2/2] COPY huggingface.tar.gz /root/:
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     FROM centos:7
   2 |
   3 | >>> COPY huggingface.tar.gz /root/
   4 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to prepare sha256:174f5685490326fc0a1c0f5570b8663732189b327007e47ff13d2ca59673db02 as ayr2wi6hpgtlcolict9wmnsjf: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b83ce1a3c26b3ee5bd749f6650b489cabae62ce9ed78e55e504d923dc793dd84/.tmp-committed493138921: no such file or directory
```