# Dockerfile issue - Why is the binary dlv not being found - No such file or directory

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, dlv

I had a docker file that was working fine. However to remote debug it , I read that I needed to install `dlv` on it and then I need to run dlv and pass the parameter of the app I am trying to debug. So after installing dlv on it and attempting to run it. I get the error

```
exec /dlv: no such file or directory
```

This is the docker file

```
    FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS builder

# Build Delve for debugging
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0


# Retrieve application dependencies.
COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./


# Build the binary.
RUN go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o fooapp

# Use the official Debian slim image for a lean production container.
FROM debian:buster-slim

EXPOSE 8000 40000

RUN set -x && apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the binary to the production image from the builder stage.
#COPY --from=builder /app/fooapp /app/fooapp #commented this out  

COPY --from=builder /go/bin/dlv /dlv

# Run dlv as pass fooapp as parameter
CMD ["/dlv", "--listen=:40000", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", "/app/fooapp"]
```

The above results in `exec /dlv: no such file or directory`

I am not sure why this is happening. Being new to docker , I have tried different ways to debug it. I tried using `dive` to check and see if the image has `dlv` on it in the path `/dlv` and it does. I have also attached an image of it

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [COPYing a file in a Dockerfile, no such file or directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997269/copying-a-file-in-a-dockerfile-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar no that does not answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You built `dlv` in `alpine`-based distro. `dlv` executable is linked against `libc.musl`:

```
# ldd dlv 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcd251d000)
        libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => not found
```

But then you switched to `glibc`-based image `debian:buster-slim`. That image doesn't have the required libraries.

```
# find / -name libc.musl*                                        
<nothing found>
```

That's why you can't execute `dlv` - the dynamic linker fails to find the proper lib.

You need to build in `glibc`-based docker. For example, replace the first line

```
FROM golang:bullseye AS builder
```

BTW. After you build you need to run the container in the priviledged mode

```
$ docker build . -t try-dlv
...
$ docker run --privileged --rm try-dlv
API server listening at: [::]:40000
2022-10-30T10:51:02Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
```

In non-priviledged container `dlv` is not allowed to spawn a child process.

```
$ docker run --rm try-dlv
API server listening at: [::]:40000
2022-10-30T10:55:46Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
could not launch process: fork/exec /app/fooapp: operation not permitted
```

**Really Minimal Image**

You use `debian:buster-slim` to minimize the image, it's size is 80 MB. But if you need a **really small** image, use `busybox`, it is only 4.86 MB overhead.

```
FROM golang:bullseye AS builder

# Build Delve for debugging
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

# Retrieve application dependencies.
COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Build the binary.
RUN go build -o fooapp .

# Download certificates
RUN set -x && apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates 

# Use the official Debian slim image for a lean production container.
FROM busybox:glibc

EXPOSE 8000 40000

# Copy the binary to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=builder /app/fooapp /app/fooapp 
# COPY --from=builder /app/ /app

COPY --from=builder /go/bin/dlv /dlv

COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl /etc/ssl

# Run dlv as pass fooapp as parameter
CMD ["/dlv", "--listen=:40000", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", "/app/fooapp"]
# ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
```

The image size is 25 MB, of which 18 MB are from `dlv` and 2 MB are from `Hello World` application.

While choosing the images care should be taken to have the same flavors of `libc`. `golang:bullseye` links against `glibc`. Hence, the minimal image must be `glibc`-based.

But if you want a bit more comfort, use `alpine` with `gcompat` package installed. It is a reasonably rich linux with lots of external packages for just extra 6 MB compared to `busybox`.

```
FROM golang:bullseye AS builder

# Build Delve for debugging
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Retrieve application dependencies.
RUN go mod tidy

# Build the binary.
RUN go build -o fooapp .

# Use alpine lean production container.
# FROM busybox:glibc
FROM alpine:latest

# gcompat is the package to glibc-based apps
# ca-certificates contains trusted TLS CA certs
# bash is just for the comfort, I hate /bin/sh
RUN apk add gcompat ca-certificates bash

EXPOSE 8000 40000

# Copy the binary to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=builder /app/fooapp /app/fooapp 
# COPY --from=builder /app/ /app

COPY --from=builder /go/bin/dlv /dlv

# Run dlv as pass fooapp as parameter
CMD ["/dlv", "--listen=:40000", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", "/app/fooapp"]
# ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Run `apt-get install musl`, then `/dlv` should work as expected.

### Explanation

Follow these steps:

1. `docker run -it <image-name> sh`
2. `apt-get install file`
3. `file /dlv`

Then you can see the following output:

```bash
/dlv: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, Go BuildID=xV8RHgfpp-zlDlpElKQb/DOLzpvO_A6CJb7sj1Nxf/aCHlNjW4ruS1RXQUbuCC/JgrF83mgm55ntjRnBpHH, not stripped
```

The confusing `no such file or directory` (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists) for related discussions) is caused by the missing `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`.

As a result, the solution is to install the `musl` library by following [its documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/musl#Installation).

My answer is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532716/running-a-containers-elf-file-without-container/55564101#55564101).

Answer (score 0):

The `no such file or directory` error indicates either your binary file does not exist, or your binary is dynamically linked to a library that does not exist.

As said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74252440/1560953), delve is linked against libc.musl. So for your delve build, you can disable `CGO` since that can result in dynamic links to libc/libmusl:

```
# Build Delve for debugging
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
...
```

This even allows you later to use a scratch build for your final target image and does not require you to install any additional packages like `musl` or use any `glibc` based image and require you to run in privileged mode.